# Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, beta

Recently I've updated from Xcode 6.2 to Xcode 6.3 beta 4 and opened my project. I had the following error on `init()`: `Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call`. Heres my `init()` method:

```
public init(image: UIImage?) {
    super.init()
    commonInit(image)
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift initializer processing is tricky and very particular. You should really read about [Swift Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) in the language documentation to understand what you're doing.

You can have more than one init method, but you have to obey the inheritance and hierarchy rules.  And you need to definitely understand what are called `convenience` initializers.

Having said that, many classes require at least one init overload like this:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

The compiler may be complaining because it thinks that's what you're trying to create but did it wrong.